# 3061 VBA Error - SQL Query "Too few parameters. Expected 1." Simple query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub lst1Model_Operation_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim sSQL As String
Dim rst As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryOrder_Model_Operation_Value WHERE Model_Operation_ID = " & CInt(Me![lst1Model_Operation].Value)

Debug.Print sSQL 'when pasted this into a query SQL, it works flawlessly.

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL) 'error line

'some code here

rst.Close
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm at loss at what to do. The `Debug.Print` looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM qryOrder_Model_Operation_Value WHERE Model_Operation_ID = 748
```

And as I said, if I paste that `Debug.Print` into a Query in the Access itself, it produces the desired results.

I have tried adding ' ' around the value, but using CInt() I already made sure it is parsed as integer. The Model_Operation_ID also expects to get an integer (otherwise it wouldn't work in a separate query either).

Edit:
The qryOder_Model_Operation_Value is as follows:

```
SELECT tbl1Model_Operation.Model_Operation_ID, tbl1Model_Operation.Model_ID, tbl1Model_Operation.Operation_Value_ID, tbl2Operation_Value.Operation_Name_ID, tbl3OperationsList.Operation_Name, tbl1Order_Model.Quantity AS [Počet párov], tbl1Order_Model.Order_ID
FROM tbl3OperationsList INNER JOIN (tbl2Operation_Value INNER JOIN (tbl1Model_Operation INNER JOIN tbl1Order_Model ON tbl1Model_Operation.Model_ID = tbl1Order_Model.Model_ID) ON tbl2Operation_Value.Operation_Value_ID = tbl1Model_Operation.Operation_Value_ID) ON tbl3OperationsList.Operation_ID = tbl2Operation_Value.Operation_Name_ID;
```

Comment: I will add it in the question itself so the formatting remains readable.

Comment: The query itself looks ok... but you are querying a Access Query which might expect a parameter?

Comment: The qryOrder_Model_Operation_Value is in the question itself now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure Access understands you want *rst* to be a `DAO.Recordset` instead of an `ADODB.Recordset`:

```vb
'Dim rst As Recordset
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
```

Both the ADO and DAO object models include `Recordset` objects.  Although similar in some respects, they can not be used interchangeably.

When your Access VBA project references include a version of ADO (*ActiveX Data Objects*) and that reference has a higher priority than the DAO reference, `Dim rst As Recordset` will give you an `ADODB.Recordset`.  Avoid unwelcome surprises by always qualifying your `Recordset` declarations with `DAO` or `ADODB` as appropriate.

Comment: You're welcome.  That didn't seem like it could be the explanation for error # 3061.  But, when you showed Alex error # **3011**, that was a dead give away.  :-)

Comment: the way .net detect number and types of parameters for the mutable functions brings a lot of surprises :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL,dbOpenTable)
```

or

```
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL,dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Comment: I get the following error: http://i.imgur.com/4FM3iNj.png on dbOpenTable and 13 - Type mismatch on dbOpenSnapshot :/.

Comment: that is much better. so tell me what is your database? is it MS Acces? we can remove `mysql` tag from OP ?

Comment: Sorry @Alex, removed the mysql tag now. Indeed my database is MS Access.